# update only rows with max(id) with condition

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I can't find a solution for my problem..

Let's say we have a simple table like this :

- id
- group_id
- flag

For the moment, the `flag` column is set to 0.

I want to update this table and set the `flag` to 1 only for rows that have the *greatest* (newest)`id` when grouped by `group_id`.

I have been testing a lot of things, without success.

Example:

```
id: 1, group_id: 1, flag: 0
id: 2, group_id: 1, flag: 0
id: 3, group_id: 1, flag: 0
id: 4, group_id: 2, flag: 0
id: 5, group_id: 2, flag: 0
```

Will become :

```
id: 1, group_id: 1, flag: 0
id: 2, group_id: 1, flag: 0
id: 3, group_id: 1, flag: 1
id: 4, group_id: 2, flag: 0
id: 5, group_id: 2, flag: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE
  yourtable t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT group_id, MAX(ID) mx_id
                           FROM yourtable
                           GROUP BY group_id) t2
  ON t1.group_id = t2.group_id AND t1.id = t2.mx_id
SET
  t1.flag = 1
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6e329/1).

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is a TSQL (SQL Server) Solution to that question.

```
UPDATE tablename
SET flag = 1
FROM (
   SELECT max(id) As maxid FROM tablename GROUP BY group_id
) A
WHERE 
  id = A.maxid
```

or even

```
UPDATE tablename
SET flag = 1 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT max(id) FROM tablename GROUP BY group_id )
```

Comment: Sorry.. You query throwing syntax errors. Did u tried or just guessed?

Comment: This is TSQL, not mySQL Syntax. I am sorry. Probably have not seen the mysql tag, or it was not present when I answered the question. I added a warning to my answer.